# Making a generic code of Angular JS by using Arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a generic code to make it in a simple way for next level purpose. Please find the commented code which I've made. But, its not working.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('mainFactory',function($http){
 return {
     getData: function() {
     return $http.get("data.json");
   }
  };
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,$http,mainFactory){    
 var data = mainFactory.getData();
 if(angular.isDefined(data)) {
     data.success(function(d,s){
        // I want this commented out code for the four lines defined below. 
        /*var a = [{name:"imagesArray"},{name:"taskArray"},{name:"courseArray"},{name:"newsArray"}];
       for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         $scope.a[i].name = d.a[i].name ? d.a[i].name : [];
       }*/

       // I dont want this number of lines. 
       $scope.imagesArray = d.imagesArray ? d.imagesArray : [];
       $scope.taskArray = d.taskArray ? d.taskArray : [];
       $scope.courseArray = d.courseArray ? d.courseArray : [];
       $scope.newsArray = d.newsArray ? d.newsArray : [];
     });
 }
});
```

If it can be simplified further, please let me know

Comment: `$scope.myArrays = d;` - Just grab a local copy of the object of arrays instead of assigning them all out to separate ones?

Comment: @MarkWalters  Can you plz update with the small snippet?

Comment: @Duncan. Thanks for your update. Can you plz post a small snippet so that I can see it.

Comment: @Syed, ok, converted comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$scope.a[i].name = d.a[i].name ? d.a[i].name : [];` to

`$scope[a[i].name] = d[a[i].name] || [];`

Comment: Awesome Thomas. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for better way to define scope property, edit your code like below:

```
data.success(function(d,s){
    var keyCollection = ["imagesArray","taskArray","courseArray","newsArray"];

    keyCollection.forEach(function(key){
        $scope[key] = d[key];
    });
});
```

---

or if your project are also using lodash(or underscore).You can simply do this(just further , don't import lodash or underscore just because this one, no need cost):

```
// outside, create advance function
var advancePick = _.partialRight(_.pick, "imagesArray", "taskArray", "courseArray", "newsArray");

data.success(function(d,s){
    // just beauty like this
    _.extend($scope, advancePick(d));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ["imagesArray","taskArray","courseArray","newsArray"];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     $scope[a[i]] = d[a[i]] ? d[a[i]] : [];
 }
```

with the name version

```
var a = [{name:"imagesArray"},{name:"taskArray"},{name:"courseArray"},{name:"newsArray"}];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     $scope[a[i].name] = d[a[i].name] ? d[a[i].name] : [];
 }
```

A last solution and the shortest most of all!

```
angular.merge($scope, d);
```

EDIT : this will work only if d is properly initialized before.

Comment: Walfrat, I didn't get the last solution?

Comment: yeah kind of tired, fixed it. angular merge will deep copy d fields in $scope.

Comment: Can you plz update a bit extra how to put your shortest solution

Comment: hum i just realized tht it won't do the part about getting an empty array if it's not initialized.... this means you have to initialized d proerly before with the loop i guess. After you can copy the whole object whenever you want using angular.merge

Comment: I appreciate on that. But, I need to know how to implement your last solution. Please update the answer with a small snippet of the same code.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can access properties two ways :

1)

```
item.property
```

2)

```
item["property"]
```

Thomas already gave you the right answer.

If you want to simplify it further, you can get rid of the definition of your "var a" array by making an object. Then you can enumerate each public property using :

```
for(var propertyName in yourObject) {
   // propertyName is is the name of each property
   // you can get the value using: yourObject[propertyName ]
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This won't work if the property has not been defined though.

Answer (score 0):

Other simplifications not related to those 4 lines:

- you don't need `$http` injected into your controller, and you don't
  need to test the result of the call to `getData()`: it returns a
  promise, take that as given.
- Also use `.then(...)` rather than the deprecated `.success(...)`.
- You
  might however want to add `.catch(...)` onto the promise to handle or
  at least log errors, but if just to log errors you can put that inside `.getData()` and keep the controller short.

Here's how those changes might look:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('mainFactory',function($http, $log){
     return {
         getData: function() {
             return $http.get("data.json")
                 .catch(function (e) { $log.error(e); });
         }
     };
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope,mainFactory){    
 mainFactory.getData()
     .then(function(d){
         // choose one of the other answers for the code here...
         var keyCollection = ["imagesArray","taskArray","courseArray","newsArray"];

         keyCollection.forEach(function(key){
             $scope[key] = d[key];
         });
      });
});
```